# How to enhance class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's consider this:

```
class Container
  def function_one
    ...
  end 
  def function_two
    ...
  end 
  def function_three
    ...
  end 
  attr_accessor :result_from_function_one 
  attr_accessor :result_from_function_two 
  attr_accessor :result_from_function_three 
end
```

Since I can't create separate algorithm body for other classes, I created four separate classes. When I need to run algorithm one, I create a class with function one, and so on:

```
class Container
  ...
end

class ContainerWithFunctionOne < Container
  def function_one
    ...
  end 
  attr_accessor :result_from_function_one 
end

class ContainerWithFunctionTwo < Container
  def function_two
    ...
  end 
  attr_accessor :result_from_function_two 
end

class ContainerWithFunctionThree < Container
  def function_three
    ...
  end 
  attr_accessor :result_from_function_three 
end
```

But when I combine `function_one` with `function_two`, I have an issue because they need to use the same data structure. So I was thinking about dividing the class `Container` into modules:

```
module FunctionOne
  class Container
    def function_one
      ...
    end 
    attr_accessor :result_from_function_one 
  end
end

module FunctionTwo
  class Container
    def function_two
      ...
    end 
    attr_accessor :result_from_function_two 
  end
end

module FunctionThree
  class Container
    def function_three
      ...
    end 
    attr_accessor :result_from_function_three
  end
end
```

But when I try to run it:

```
require_relative 'FunctionOne'
require_relative 'FunctionTwo'
require_relative 'FunctionThree'

containter = Container.new
container.function_one
container.function_two
container.function_three
```

it gave a run time error:

```
in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Container (NameError)
```

and I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Guessing from the what you are trying to achieve, I suggest you take a look at Decorator design pattern or maybe Chain-of-Responsibility design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
container = FunctionOne::Container.new
```

to create a new container